# Is there a difference between these 2 left joins in Oracle SQL? and why

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

```
SELECT * 
FROM TAB1 
LEFT JOIN TAB2 ON TAB2.ID_TAB1 = TAB1.ID 
JOIN TAB3 ON TAB3.ID = TAB2.ID_TAB3;
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM TAB1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
           FROM TAB2
           JOIN TAB3 ON TAB3.ID = TAB2.ID_TAB3) T
ON T.ID_TAB1 = TAB1.ID;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, they are different - the inner join to TAB3 (*after* the left join to TAB2) in the first query effectively turns the left join back into an inner join.

The brackets in the second query ensure that the inner join to TAB3 is evaluated *before* the left join - so it remains a left join to TAB2, returning *only* those TAB2 records where there is a corresponding TAB3 record (otherwise, the TAB1 records are returned with corresponding NULLs).

Comment: isn't this a side effect ? when i write LEFT i want a LEFT join to that table and all its joins.

Comment: Well, you could always write to Oracle (and the other DB providers and ANSI) and tell them that they're doing it wrong...

Comment: Why they transform the LEFT into a INNER ?

Comment: @CosminVacaroiu: They don't transform anything. You second condition (on the `JOIN`) makes it effectively an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @CosminVacaroiu: To put it another way: in your first query, you first left join TAB1 to TAB2; *then*, the data set produced by joining these two tables together is itself **inner joined** to TAB3 based on the fields in TAB2. Since these fields will be NULL where the TAB2 records do not exist, you will therefore be attempting to inner join to TAB3 on the condition `TAB3.ID=NULL`, which *never* evaluates as true.

Answer (score 2):

What you might want is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TAB1 
LEFT JOIN TAB2
JOIN TAB3
 ON TAB3.ID = TAB2.ID_TAB3
 ON TAB2.ID_TAB1 = TAB1.ID;
```

In your first query, after you have the `LEFT JOIN` and it's associated `ON` clause, then the next `JOIN` (of any kind) is against that entire constructed potential result set (i.e. the already joined `TAB2` and `TAB1`). And that next join being an `INNER JOIN`, it must be satisfied completely for the join to complete.

Whereas in the above query, I've introduced a `LEFT JOIN`, but don't introduce it's associated `ON` clause until after I've completed a further join on the "right hand side" of the left join.

---

Just has to download, install Oracle Express. This script:

```
CREATE TABLE TAB1 (
    ID int not null
);
CREATE TABLE TAB2 (
    ID_TAB1 int not null,
    ID_TAB3 int not null
);
CREATE TABLE TAB3 (
    ID int not null
);
INSERT INTO TAB1 (ID) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO TAB1 (ID) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO TAB3 (ID) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO TAB3 (ID) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO TAB2 (ID_TAB1,ID_TAB3) VALUES (2,2);
SELECT * 
FROM TAB1 
LEFT JOIN TAB2
JOIN TAB3
 ON TAB3.ID = TAB2.ID_TAB3
 ON TAB2.ID_TAB1 = TAB1.ID;
```

Worked, and ran as expected.

---

It might be easier to think about what this query does if you think of `JOIN` as introducing a left parenthesis `(`, and `ON` introducing a right parenthesis `)`. Then, the `JOIN`s and `ON` are matched in the same way that parenthesis are usually matched.

Or, another equal way, would be to consider each join clause to be "open" until its corresponding `ON` is encountered. But the rule for matching an `ON` to a `JOIN` is to find the closest "open" `JOIN`.

Either way, in the above query, the first `ON` clause satisfies the join between `TAB2` and `TAB3`. The second `ON` clause then satisfies the `LEFT JOIN` between `TAB1` and the joined (`TAB2` and `TAB3`).

Comment: don't know, but you can't have join without on, or 2 on's

Comment: Oh, I see what you meant. Edited. It is valid ANSI syntax.

Comment: @Damien: Sorry for the (wrong) updates. I think it needs parentheses to work.

Comment: @CosminVacaroiu - Fine, I'll waste 20 minutes of my time and download and install Oracle Express. I've added the script I ran for the test. So, there is *not* a syntax error.

Comment: @ypercube - Nope, just downloaded Oracle express and tested it. Parentheses might make it easier to read, but it's correct without them.